# Is it mandatory for DbContext to be injected .InPerRequestScope in ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have been using Ninject IoC container in my ASP.NET MVC3 portal. Whenever I've been injecting Entity Framework `DbContext` in `PerThread` scope, my data wasn't consistent, changes would not get displayd for some time after I've made changes to Entities, etc.

After I've switched the IoC configuration to resolve a fresh copy of my `DbContext` instance for each request (`PerRequestScope()`), all the problems were gone.

So is it absolutely mandatory to use PerRequest injection strategy in MVC3 applications?

Comment: Your data was inconsistent because the DbContext was disposed before the object depending on it did. Changing to the per http request solves this problem.

Comment: @TravisJ: That's not true; pet-thread scopes dispose _later_.

Comment: @SLaks - Isn't that the point? Wasn't the data inconsistent due to the context being disposed?

Comment: @TravisJ: No; the data was inconsistent because the context was _not_ disposed.  See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is mandatory.

Your problem works like this:

- Thread A loads an entity
- Thread B modifies that entity
- The next request to Thread A uses the cached entity from the first request, ignoring the changes

Comment: +1 with a bit of explicitness: it's mandatory for every service that directly or indirectly contains a DbContext. If you have other services that don't contain a DbContext, these can be configured with different lifetime scopes.