# Instantiating a DbContext in a repository instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject

In ASP.NET MVC3 application, my controllers will work with the set of BL "manager" classes, which, in turn, will make use of repositories. These repositories rely on EF DbContext instances to perform its duties.

I am planning to configure IoC container to do a dependency injection the following way (in data module)

```
Bind<StoreContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
Bind<ICatUserRepository>().To<GenericUserRepository>().InRequestScope();
```

`StoreContext` is a `DbContext`. It is constructor-injected into a `GenericUserRepository`.
This way, I assume, [the rule of my DbContext to be instantiated in also PerRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122480/is-it-mandatory-for-dbcontext-to-be-injected-inperrequestscope-in-asp-net-appli) will remain fulfilled, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it certainly would be - since `ICatUserRepository` is resolved on a request scope level the IoC container will at that point (for each request) create a new instance of `GenericUserRepository` after resolving its dependencies for constructor injection.

Resolving the the `StoreContext` dependency means the  IoC container will go through the binding for `StoreContext`, check if there already is an existing instance of `StoreContext` *for the current request* and if not create a fresh copy to inject - In your case that means you get a new instance of `StoreContext` for each new request.